# 12.04: Kernel panic - not syncing: Attemped to kill the idle task!

Tags: 12.04, kernel

My parents got this error on their machine, so I'm not sure what triggered it. My dad says it just happens randomly. It apparently happens every couple of days, but this is the first time I've been told about it. The computer is pretty old and is low on hard drive space, which I think might be the issue.

Here's the entire output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJFRK.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvQB6.jpg

If you can't read that, let me know.

Comment: did you solve the problem? I'm getting the same error and trying to understand what's wrong with my ASUS B85M-G configuration and Ubuntu 14 installation

Comment: @yetanothercoder I think it went away after we cleared up a bunch of hard drive space, but this was a year ago so I'm not sure